# Django: Exception as "No module named engine"

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm using Django 1.7.7. I installed debug toolbar with:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar.git#egg=django-debug-toolbar
```

I followed prerequisites from [this page](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#prerequisites).

After everything is set up I get the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error importing debug panel debug_toolbar.panels.templates: "No module named engine"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569760/django-debug-toolbar-template-object-has-no-attribute-engine

Comment: @ArunGhosh - I don't think that's a duplicate. Sandy is using Django 1.7.7 and the Django template language. The other question is using Django 1.8 and Jinja.

Answer (score 8):

[Django Debug Toolbar 1.5 requires Django 1.8+](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changes.html#id1). Since you are using Django 1.7.7, try installing 1.4 instead.

```
pip install django-debug-toolbar==1.4
```

Note that Django 1.7.X is no longer supported, so does not receive security fixes. You should upgrade to the 1.8 LTS or later as soon as possible.

Comment: I can't upgrade django version as there are a lot dependency on production. A per above comment by 'Arun' i am able to see the django toolbar but when hitting my URL & clicking the SQL tab from django debug toolbar I am getting as 'Internal Server error'

Comment: If you can't upgrade Django, then install debug toolbar 1.4 as I suggested. I can't help you with Arun's comment, especially if all you say is 'Internal Server Error'.

Comment: Ok.Thanks Alasdair